# Post Database upgrade on new instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, migration, upgrade

I reviewed the SQL Server 2012 technical upgrade guide and also googled for more recommendations.

I am migrating a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance to SQL Server 2012 on a separate machine.

Here is what I plan to do. Please correct and advise your recommendations.

- On SQL Server 2008 R2 instance:

  - I ran the SQL Server upgrade advisor instance.
  - Take backup after all activity is stopped.
- On SQL Server 2012 instance:

  - Restored SQL Server 2008 R2 backups
  - Update the database compatibility level to 110
  - `dbcc checkdb  with data_purity`
  - `EXEC sp_updatestats;`
  - `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN';`
  - `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(dbname);`

I will have the logins, job setup separately.

Do I need to rebuild the indexes? Any thing else?

I truly value your input and hope to hear your recommendations.

Thank you.

Comment: I read through some more material but would like clarification on the following - Do I need to rebuild index post migration or just update stats or both? Is this correct?
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=OFF)';
GO
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'; 
GO

Comment: Update stats is highly recommended. Rebuilding all indexes without looking into their fragmentation levels, is waste of resources - but if you have window to do it, then go for it. Also, `sp_MSforeachtable` is undocumented. Better use Ola's maintenance solution that my answer refers to. HTH !